# Return HTML + CSS in lambda handler

Tags: python, lambda, jmeter, github-actions

I am using lambda function to return the html file

```
def handler(event, context):    
with ZipFile('/report/testreport.zip', 'r') as zip:
    zip.extractall('/tmp')
with open('/tmp/index.html', 'r') as html_file:
    html = html_file.read()

return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    },
    "body": html
}
```

zip file is the test report of Jmeter

[image]

This is the html of Jmeter report

[image]

The actual result is exported

[image]

Are there any ways to get all html + css to easy to read.

I need to upload all them to github work flow

[image]

Comment: Can you share the contents of `index.html`?

Comment: I am sorry, I can not share this file

Comment: Is your css within the `index.html` as inline css or as a separate css file?

Comment: It is a separate css file, I am researching about compress all folder and return it , use function url to download them.

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/zip, application/octet-stream",
            "Content-disposition":"attachment; filename=/tmp/report.zip"
        },
        "body": "test"
    }

Comment: Thats your issue. If you have a separate css file, you need a lambda handler to serve that css file. Or you can use inline css in your `index.html`